# MYSQL Additional select on same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table called words:

```
word(text) team(number)

a          1
b          1
c          2
d          3
e          1
f          1
```

When i am doing mysql query i know only the word, so it looks like

```
SELECT word FROM words WHERE word = 'e'
```

However, i would like to **append** other words in same team

so my query would return 4 rows:

1. e
2. a
3. b
4. f

same word could be in the result set twice.

Could anybody help me which would be best method to use?
UNION SELECT , INNER JOIN or what?

Thank you

UPDATE: After testing i realized that i need to **append** other records, that is, originally selected word be first.
Also renamed "group" to "team" to avoid confusion.

For testing:

```
create table words(word text, team int);
insert into words (word, team) values('a', 1),('b', 1),('c', 2),('d', 2),('e',1),('f',1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like

`SELECT b.word FROM WORDS a LEFT JOIN WORDS b ON a.team = b.team WHERE a.word = 'a'`

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd30f/1)

ugly but does what you want in SQL

`SELECT word FROM words WHERE word = 'e' 
UNION 
SELECT b.word FROM WORDS a 
LEFT JOIN WORDS b ON a.team = b.team 
WHERE a.word = 'e' AND b.word != 'e'`

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd30f/9)

Comment: Hi, first "word" will be flagged as ambiguous.

Comment: Syntax error: 
use near 'a.team = b.team WHERE a.word = 'e' at line 1: SELECT a.word FROM words a LEFT JOIN words b USING a.team = b.team WHERE a.word = 'e'

Comment: Sorry should be ON, or maybe USING(word). In terms of returning the original word first I don't think that will be easy with sql alone, you'l probably be better off doing that in the code especially as you already have the first word.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it would return 4 rows of "e", nothing more.
Doing JOIN would actually append data, no?

Comment: Sorry I'm not testing it, I think the last edit should fix it

Comment: Thanks, it works, but original word is not first. It's hard to explain, i cannot simply pick it with a script.

Comment: Have to accept it as an answer. Does the job.
Wonder if anybody could come up with cleaner query.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is getting more complex.

Here is a potential solution that uses a union and a sub-query to get the results.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd30f/6)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
create table words(word text, team int);
insert into words (word, team) values('a', 1),('b', 1),('c', 2),('d', 2),('e',1),('f',1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT word FROM words WHERE word = "e"

UNION

(SELECT word FROM words
  WHERE team = (SELECT team FROM words WHERE word = "e")
  AND word != "e"
  ORDER BY word)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd30f/6/0)**:

```
| WORD |
--------
|    e |
|    a |
|    b |
|    f |
```

Comment: @Simba, as for all optimization questions.  a) measure to find out, b) don't worry until you have a problem.  My gut says you won't measure a difference unless the table is quite large.  Personally I find this easier to read than a join.

Comment: After trying i realised i need originally selected word to be first, so i am forced to used some JOIN. After trying couple i was unsuccessful. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `OR`

```
    SELECT  word  FROM words 
    where `group` in (select `group` from words where word = 'a' )
```

JUST to let you know that you have column `group` which is reserved keyword , dont forget to use backticks when selecting it.

Comment: This is not what i need. I need to select additional rows based on first select group (other words in same group)
the "group" is used only in example, thanks :)